# Sass 3.3 new feature @at-root doesn't seem to compile

Tags: css, sass

According to Sass 3.3 release notes the following code should work.

```
@mixin element($name)
{
    @at-root #{&}__#{$name}
    {
        @content;
    }
}
```

I would like to use it for BEM syntax css generation..

But instead it throws an error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "@at-root #{": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "&}__#{$name}" on line 3 of dist/mixins/_element.scss
```

sass --version gives *Sass 3.3.1 (Maptastic Maple)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using a slightly out of date version of the syntax. Try this:

```
@mixin element($name)
{
    @at-root &__#{$name}
    {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sdsanders! Obviously i need to utilise suffixes feature better. :D